# Flash CS 4 / AS 2 + Dynamic Text + Html + Embedded fonts

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, embedded-resource, dynamic-text

I have this scenario:

1) I have a dynamic text that receives its data from a XML.
2) The texts showed get theirs style from a CSS file.
3) My dynamic text has a html 'span' tag and it's formatted according to the CSS class that it's passed via the XML file.

Ok... so far so good. It's something like:

```
_root.txt.txtDica = "<span class='"+ node.childNodes[_global.auxCont].attributes.myStyle +"'>" + node.childNodes[_global.auxCont].attributes.myText+ "</span>";
```

The problem is that the swf has a poor quality text. So, I've been looking around, found some things about embedded fonts, Flash TextField() and etc. But, nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know how can I generate this html tag in a dynamic text with a good quality? It's worth to say that I'm using regular fonts, such as Verdana and Arial.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would embed the characters just the characters you need.

> 1 - Click on your dynamic textField on
>   the stage,
>
> 2 - Select 'Antialias for
>   readablility' in the property
>   inspector.
>
> 3 - Click EMBED in the property
>   inspector.
>
> 4 - In the EMBED popup, choose 'basic
>   Latin', 'Latin extended', or any
>   charsets that you need, or paste in
>   the characters you need in the box on
>   the bottom of the popup.

That should be it!  You CSS styles should still work fine.